# No Text Displayed for the Installer while Attempting to Install to MacBook Pro 13" Retina

Tags: software-installation, fonts, macbook, text

I'm having issues trying to install Ubuntu side by side with OS X on a 2015 MacBook Pro 13" model with Retina. I have the MacBook12,1 model. When I attempt to run the installer, I see the usual GUI but every window contains no text. I've tried both USB and CDs as a means of installing Ubuntu with the same results. I have the same symptoms when I run the trial version as well. Is there a compatibility issue with the newer MacBooks and 14.04 and 14.10 versions when it comes to fonts? I've tried Googling and searched several forums but it seems I can't find anyone with this problem. I've never seen this before installing Ubuntu an any machine. Any help is appreciated. :)

[image]

Comment: @Ryan can you take a picture of the screen and upload it, it might help.

Comment: Sure thing. I'm at work right now but I'll include a screen shot later today.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay, but I've been swamped lately. What's the best way to attach a screenshot to a comment? I'm looking around this page and I don't see a link or any way I can paste the image.

Comment: I used to dropbox to share the image so hopefully this link works. Please let me know if you can see this...  https://www.dropbox.com/s/lh4w3q8mojpyi9m/IMG_0180.JPG?dl=0

Comment: Cool, got it in there.

Comment: Hello All. This is still unresolved. I'm curious to know if anyone has a lead I can follow to resolve this on my own. Has anyone experienced this before. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I had the exact same thing happen to me when installing 15.04 on my desktop. No text on the GUI installer. It was really annoying to figure out what was going wrong.

Turns out the noveau driver was doing weird things so I had to manually append "nomodeset" in the boot options.

Solution:

1. Hit *Spacebar* on first purple screen when booting from the installer. This will take you to some extra installer options.
2. Highlight "Install Ubuntu" by using your arrow keys.
3. Add "nomodeset" to the Boot options command line (I added it at the end before the "--")
4. Hit *Enter* to start the installer without mode setting.

If this worked you should see the Ubuntu splash screen start in a low-res mode.

NOTE: I had to **manually** append "nomodeset". There is an F6 menu that can select nomodeset too but that did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried version 15.04 and all appears to be well now. I suppose that 14.04 and 14.10 is not entirely compatible with the latest MacBook models.